# How to install Data Protector RPM patch in Linux?

Tags: linux, rpm, patch-management, data-protector

Well, HPE Data Protector has a long tradition of doing odd things.
For example the way an `rpm` "patch" is installed is not via `-U` or `-F`, but differently, which brings me to my question:

In the past every patch was accompanied by a corresponding `.txt` file that listed dependencies and installation instructions.
However for the current 11.01 release I fail to find such files, and I wonder how to install the patches available.

(In the recent past there were no patches, just new releases, but this time there exist patches, and I wonder how to install these.
Having search the full documentation I still could not find instructions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look into `onmisetup.sh`, and I found commands like

> rpm -U --replacepkgs --replacefiles --nodeps ...

and

> rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs --replacefiles --nodeps ...

So I tried the variant `rpm -Uv --replacepkgs --replacefiles ...` and that seemed to have succeeded.